# DJI_SDK damping check failed with TRACE_COORDINATED mode

Tags: ros, dji-sdk

I'm working with **ROS_DJI_OSDK** version 3.7 and dji matrice M600. Until this day I used for my autonomous missions **TRACE_POINT** mode defined in `MissionWaypointTask.msg` [here](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Onboard-SDK-ROS/blob/3.7/dji_sdk/msg/MissionWaypointTask.msg#L14-L16) and everything worked fine. But I would like to do the same with **TRACE_COORDINATED** mode with some damping between waypoints.

The problem is even if I set damping to 0 I get this error message:

```
STATUS/1 @ getErrorCodeMessage, L656: missionWpUploadCallback
STATUS/1 @ getCMDSetMissionMSG, L883: WAYPOINT_MISSION_CHECK_FAILED

[ INFO] [1538563753.039855552]: waypoint mission initialized and uploaded
[ WARN] [1538563753.040152078]: ack.info: set = 3 id = 17
[ WARN] [1538563753.040214866]: ack.data: 231
[ WARN] [1538563753.040261163]: Failed sending waypoint upload command
```

The **ack.data** equal to 231 means `damping checking failed` message. But whatever I set the damping to the result stays the same.

I've read [here](https://phantompilots.com/threads/damping-check-failed.69444/) that there is some restriction about damping: 
*"Actually we don't have the limitation for the 1/2 distance. However, we have the restriction that the Damping distance for Waypoint A plus the damping distance for Waypoint B should be smaller than the distance between A and B"* But with damping equal to 0 or other small value it should be alright with this restriction.

Is there something I've missed here?

This is my default configuration of the whole `MissionWaypointTask` and each `WaypointSettings`:

```
waypoint_task.velocity_range = 10;
waypoint_task.idle_velocity = 5;
waypoint_task.action_on_finish = dji_sdk::MissionWaypointTask::FINISH_NO_ACTION;
waypoint_task.mission_exec_times = 1;
waypoint_task.yaw_mode = dji_sdk::MissionWaypointTask::YAW_MODE_AUTO;
waypoint_task.trace_mode = dji_sdk::MissionWaypointTask::TRACE_COORDINATED;
waypoint_task.action_on_rc_lost = dji_sdk::MissionWaypointTask::ACTION_AUTO;
waypoint_task.gimbal_pitch_mode = dji_sdk::MissionWaypointTask::GIMBAL_PITCH_FREE;

waypoint_settings.damping = 0;
waypoint_settings.yaw = 0;
waypoint_settings.gimbalPitch = 0;
waypoint_settings.turnMode = 0;
waypoint_settings.hasAction = 0;
waypoint_settings.actionTimeLimit = 100;
waypoint_settings.actionNumber = 0;
waypoint_settings.actionRepeat = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
    waypoint_settings.commandList[i] = 0;
    waypoint_settings.commandParameter[i] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I've figured it out. I was setting the whole time `damping_distance` to 0 which is not supported by the **DJI SDK**. Other values seem to be valid.